# Sending a rigidbody2d towards a certain point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, rigid-bodies

Im spawning an object outside of the screen and i want to send it towards the middle. The DrawLine shows me that the targets direction is correct. But the object goes of in any random direction. Whats wrong with my calculation?

```
// add force towards center of screen
    var targetPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-3, 3), Random.Range(-3, 3),00);
    var forceAmount = 10f;
    rb2d.AddForce((bigasteroid.transform.position - targetPosition).normalized * forceAmount);
    Debug.DrawLine(targetPosition, bigasteroid.transform.position,Color.red,3f);
```

Comment: could you add some more code? Is this code in update() scope?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are passing the opposite direction to AddForce. Try this:

```
rb2d.AddForce((targetPosition - bigasteroid.transform.position).normalized * forceAmount);
```